# Avfoundation - Play and record video (along with audio and preview) simultaneously

Tags: iphone, video, avfoundation, video-capture, recording

I am trying to record and play video simultaneously. Is this possible with avfoundation? Currently i am able to do it as long as i dont record audio. As soon as i add audio input to AVCaptureSession and restart the whole thing i receive "AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification" and recording stops.

This is how i play video.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]     initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.playerView.bounds];
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession=NO;
self.player = moviePlayer;

[moviePlayer release];

[self.playerView addSubview:player.view];

[player play];
```

And this is how I record video:

```
NSError *error;

AVCamCaptureManager *captureManager = [[AVCamCaptureManager alloc] init];



if ([captureManager setupSessionWithPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow error:&error])
{
    [self setCaptureManager:captureManager];



     AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[captureManager session]];
     self.captureVideoPreviewLayer= previewLayer;

     UIView *view = [self cameraView];
     CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
     [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

     CGRect bounds = [view bounds];


     [captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

     if ([captureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported]) 
     [captureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];


     [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];


   [[captureManager session] startRunning];

    [self setCaptureVideoPreviewLayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    if ([[captureManager session] isRunning])
    {
        [captureManager setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
        [captureManager setDelegate:self];


        [viewLayer insertSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];

        NSString *countString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", [[AVCaptureDevice devices] count]];
        NSLog(@"Device count: %@",countString);


    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                            message:@"Failed to start session."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

    }
} else {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Input Device Init Failed"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];        
}

[captureManager release];
if (![[self captureManager] isRecording]) {
    [[self captureManager] startRecording];
}
```

Where as i am using "AVCamCaptureManager" from apple AVCam sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, set the moviePlayer to use the application audio session:

```
moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession=YES;
```

Then, **before** calling **[[captureManager session] startRunning]**, activate an audio session with its category set to "play and record" and override its property to allow it to mix with others.

```
// Set audio session category to "play and record"
NSError* error = nil;
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
if (![audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setCategory failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// Set audio session property "allow mixing" to true so audio can be recorded while it is playing
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
OSStatus status = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);
if (status != kAudioSessionNoError) {
    NSLog(@"AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers) failed: %ld", status);
}

// Activate the audio session
error = nil;
if (![audioSession setActive:YES error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession setActive:YES failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, since it contradicts the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10559420/954643 which says to start the audio session after the capture session.

Comment: Actually, the docs say this about `useApplicationAudioSession`: "A Boolean value that indicates whether the movie player should use the app’s audio session. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. There is not replacement for this property and its use is discouraged.)"  Default value is `YES` already.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone else is wondering... I got the above approach to work as well that Wertesse proposed, but it also works with an AVPlayer (which doesn't have the useApplicationAudioSession attribute).

Comment: Hey Bernt, Is there any additional insight on how to get this to work? I effectively duplicated the code in the original question in my viewDidLoad function and I added the AudioSession configuration. However, my CaptureSession is still being stopped. Code sample would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!