# Connect to iPhone Loudspeaker Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

i have successfully used AVFoundation Framework to record, stop, and play the same.
I just wanted to know whether or not I can route this audio directly to the speaker.

In a way, when i record/speak it should be routed directly to the speaker at the same time and i should be able to listen what i speak.

That is it should adapt a synchronous behaviour.

I hope to get your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991452/avfoundation-play-and-record-video-along-with-audio-and-preview-simultaneous

Comment: @Houssni : I tried to look up to almost all post revolving around Loudspeakers but eventually none of them seem to fit my requirement.

Comment: @JasperBlues :  To some extent. I have no deep idea about AVFoundation Framework.If i could get a some brief detail about my question.Thank you by the way for giving me a clue to start with.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google Search brings up a tutorial by RayWenderlich:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios